# One session per user in Rails 3 with Thoughtbot Clearance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, clearance

Is there an established way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't you create a boolean in each employee. Once they login, the controller would update attributes to that boolean to flag it as yes. If the field is already set to yes then it will not allow the login. Potential problems would be user closing browser instead of logging out and remember me sessions.

Comment: Yes, and for that reason I am leaning towards using sessions. Possibly saving the value in the database AND in a session, in case the user tries to log in from a separate browser. Just wondering if there's an easy way to do this with clearance. I imagine it's a common pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking how to make Clearance work such that the user can only be logged in on one machine at a time?  (i.e.  a user signing in on a particular machine ends their session anywhere else they're signed in?)

If so, [here's your answer (Clearance wiki)](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/wiki/concurrent-sign-in)

If not, can you clarify your question?